# Using jmh to benchmark code without creating separate maven project

Tags: java, maven, benchmarking, jmh

I am working on a Maven project and I wish to use jmh to benchmark my code. I want to organize my project so that it contains the source code, unit tests, and benchmarks. There seems to be a way in gradle to benchmark your code without creating a separate gradle project (see [link](http://gvsmirnov.ru/blog/tech/2014/03/10/keeping-your-benchmarks-separate.html)). Is there a way to do this in Maven?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer is *yes*.

I came across to this directory layout in my projects (but you definitely can change it)

```
+- src/
   +- main/java   - sources
   +- test/
      +- java        - test sources
      +- perf        - benchmarks
```

You need a couple of plugins to achieve that.

1. [`build-helper-maven-plugin`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) to attach custom test sources location

```xml
<execution>
    <id>add-test-source</id>
    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>add-test-source</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <sources>
            <source>src/test/perf</source>
        </sources>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

2. [`maven-compiler-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) to run [`jmh-generator-annprocess`](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22jmh-generator-annprocess%22) annotation processor on `test-compile` phase

```xml
<execution>
    <goals>
        <goal>testCompile</goal>
    </goals>

    <configuration>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmh-generator-annprocess</artifactId>
                <version>${jmh.version}</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

3. [`maven-assembly-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to create runnable jar with benchmarks

```xml
<execution>
    <id>make-assembly</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <attach>true</attach>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>org.openjdk.jmh.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

```xml
<assembly>
    <id>perf-tests</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
            <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

After that you'll get an executable jar with benchmarks which could be run as usual

```
java -jar target/your-project-version-perf-tests.jar
```

You can see working example [here](https://github.com/KetothXupack/stackoverflow-answers/tree/master/q38880911).

***NOTE***

The only drawback of this solution is that all test classes and test dependencies will also be included in jar with benchmarks which definitely bloats it up. But you can avoid it by compiling benchmarks in separate (other than `${project.build.directory}/test-classes`) directory.

Comment: In your working example (i.e., doSomethingTest in ExampleBenchmark.java), it's better to avoid the for loop, as it leads to unintended performance results due to loop optimizations in the JVM.

Comment: Having `src/test/perf` besides `src/test/java` is a bit inconsistent, since the latter distinguishes the artifacts by technology (java in this case) and the former distinguishes it by purpose (perf). Since the benchmarks are probably written in Java too, I would prefer `src/perf/java`, as suggested in this article about [setting up JMH with Gradle](http://gvsmirnov.ru/blog/tech/2014/03/10/keeping-your-benchmarks-separate.html).

Comment: Where does the `<assembly>` element go?  I don't see it in your working example's pom.xml

Comment: Oh, I see it in `src/main/assembly/perf-tests.xml`